# Roll the dice problem in ReplyKeyboardMarkup of telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot

I wrote a telegram bot that gives users ReplyKeyboardMarkup to roll the dice.
For android and pc users everything is good, but for ios users when they click on 
they just send a text instance of  although must be sent a rolled one.